# run asp on local computer

Tags: asp-classic

i have tried to run following asp code,which is written in  html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("hello world ");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i run it,got following one

```
<% response.write("hello world "); %>
```

so i guessed,there is not running server or something like this,so  what could i do?i have installed apache,mysql servers,what  else do i need?sorry if my question is not so prffessional asked,because i am new in asp language,i have took  this example from this site

http://w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_text

Comment: Which operating system or version of IIS are you using?

Comment: For installing IIS in Windows 7 you can take a look at this http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of IIS (like 7.5 on Win7), the ASP DLL is not installed by default. Even IIS might not be installed by default. You can add them using `appwiz.cpl` (System Settings >> Add/Remove Software >> Windows Components). See [Running Classic ASP Applications on IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=82731) for a reference.

Then there's one additional bit you absolutely want to enable for development, and that is to [set `scriptErrorSentToBrowser = true` in `inetmgr` (IIS manager)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/). Alternatively you could enable [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/565/using-failed-request-tracing-to-troubleshoot-classic-asp-errors/), which <strike>I haven't tried</strike> I have just tried [following this MSDN doc (Enable Trace Logging for Failed Requests (IIS 7))](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28WS.10%29.aspx) and it's really worth while enabling this!

Answer (score 0):

Html can be run on a browser.but for running an asp code,
you need a server.So you must to write the code
in .asp extension file,not in html and have to install IIS.

go to link http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_install.asp to install IIS.

create a folder in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot
suppose your folde name is xxx
put your .asp file there
go to the folder properties you've created(xxx folder). click security option. then click
edit and allow full control there.

run the folder in your browser as localhost/xxx/yourfilename.asp

Comment: Just FYI; W3Schools is a *horrible* place to recommend people go to. It's information is quite often outdated or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS installed, you hit the nail on the head when you said:

> i have tried to run following asp code,which is written in html file

Change your `.html` file to `.asp`

ASP code will not execute unless in a `.asp` file.